# How do I package a python virtualenv project for distribution?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I've tried using pyinstaller and cxfreeze but they seem to be using my site-wide packages and are missing the correct dependencies. Is there a straightforward way to package a python app with all the dependencies listed in requirements.txt?

Thanks

Comment: cx_Freeze works by scanning your code for imports. You can specify extra dependencies in the setup script ([docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html)). I think PyInstaller works in a similar way.